# Why is that a row added using the dataframe loc function does not give the correct result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to insert a new row  to a dataframe named 'my_df1' using the my_df1.loc function.But in the result ,the new row added has NaN values

```
my_data = {'A':pd.Series([1,2,3]),'B':pd.Series([4,5,6]),'C':('a','b','c')}
my_df1 = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
print(my_df1)
my_df1.loc[3] = pd.Series([5,5,5])
```

Result displayed is as below

```
    A    B    C
0  1.0  4.0    a
1  2.0  5.0    b
2  3.0  6.0    c
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: use a list `my_df1.loc[3] = [5,5,5]` or an `np.array` like `my_df1.loc[3] = np.ones(3)*5`, or even just a scalar `my_df1.loc[3] =5`

Answer (score 1):

The reason that is all `NaN` is that `my_df1.loc[3]` as index `(A,B,C)` while `pd.Series([5,5,5])` as index `(0,1,2)`. When you do `series1=series2`, pandas only copies values of common indices, hence the result.

To fix this, do as @anky_91 says, or if you already has a series, use its values:

```
my_df1.loc[3] = my_series.values
```

Comment: I changed the column names from (A,B,C) to (0,1,2) and tried again. And it worked .Thanks Quang Hoang .

Comment: Also it worked with the below change

my_df1.loc[3] = pd.Series([5,5,5],index = ('A','B','C'))

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out how to add a Series as a row or column to a dataframe

my_data = {'A':pd.Series([1,2,3]),'B':pd.Series([4,5,6]),'C':('a','b','c')}
my_df1 = pd.DataFrame(my_data)

print(my_df1)

## Code1 adds a new column 'D' and values 5,5,5 to the dataframe

my_df1.loc[:,'D'] = pd.Series([5,5,5],index = my_df1.index)
print(my_df1)

## Code2 adds a new row with index 3 and values 3,4,3,4 to the dataframe in code 1

my_df1.loc[3] = pd.Series([3,4,3,4],index = ('A','B','C','D'))
print(my_df1)